# Remove some percentage of elements from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of unknown length in java.
I want to remove 1 percent of the total elements of the array after sorting it.
How can I do that? If I pass an array and a length to a function.

```
public double deleteElements(double array[], int length) {
    int trimmedLength = array.length-length;
    for (int i = 0; i < trimmedLength; i++) {               
    }    
}
```

Comment: Your problem statement is a little bit ambiguous. Please, provide more info.

Comment: As said above, do you want to remove % of elements from the head or the tail of the array?

Comment: Your question is not clear, reorganize it.

Comment: Which percent do you need to remove ? The first percent ? The last one ? any consecutive value that takes 1% in the array by using the index of the first one ? One element every ten element ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean something like :

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test{

        public static void main(String[] args){

            double[] testArray = new double[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

            //implement sort, if needed

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString( deleteElements(testArray, 5) ));
        }

        public static double[] deleteElements(double array[],int newLength){

            //add check array != null
            //add check length is <= array.length

            double[] returnArray = new double[newLength];

            for(int i=0;i<newLength;i++){
              returnArray[i] = array[i];
            }

            return returnArray;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an assumption that the length you are passing in is the percent of elements you want to remove from the list.

This converts your array to a list, sorts it, and converts the remaining percentage back to an array which is returned.

```
public double[] deleteElements(double[] doubles, int length)
  {
    List<Double> elements = Arrays.stream(doubles).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(elements);
    int startElement = (int) (elements.size() / 100.0 * length);

    List<Double> subList = elements.subList(startElement, elements.size());

    return subList.stream().mapToDouble(d -> d).toArray();
  }
```